# "No handles with labels found to put in legend" Error when doing subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend, subplot

I am facing the issue *No handles with labels found to put in legend* it's due to `subplot.legend()`
this line of code.

In this code I am making two bar graphs simultaneously the desire output and current program output is given below.

I strongly believe I am missing a small thing.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#reading data
data = pd.read_csv('Malicious_or_criminal_attacks_breakdown-Top_five_industry_sectors_July-Dec-2019.csv',index_col=0,engine='python')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


#df list for data
df.values.tolist()

#construction of group bar chart
labels = ('Cyber incident', 'Theft of paperwork or data storagedevice', 'Rogue employee', 'Social engineering / impersonation')
colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green']
identify=['Health service providers','Finance','Education','Legal,accounting & management services','Personal services']

data = df.values.tolist()
arr = np.array(data)


n_groups, n_colors = arr.shape

width = 0.2
x_pos = np.arange(n_colors)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(14, 5), dpi=100)

for i in range(n_groups):
    plt.bar(x_pos + i*width, arr[i, :], width, align='center', label=labels[i], color=colors[i])
 

for subplot in ax:
        subplot.set_xlabel("the top five industry sectors")
        subplot.set_ylabel("Number of attack")
        subplot.set_title("Type of attack by top five industry sectors")
        subplot.set_xticks(x_pos+width/2)
        subplot.set_xticklabels(identify,rotation=89.5)
        subplot.legend()
```

Comment: @mapf Please Help me Out!!

Comment: The problem is that you didn't plot anything in your first `axes`, thus calling `subplot.legend()` will give you that error.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh I think you get the point. Can you please modify the code. I have been trying since morning and its night here now :(. Thanking for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a legend for each of the multiple subplots, you can set up the axs, create each graph in an array, and then set up a legend for it.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(14, 5), dpi=100)

for i in range(n_groups):
    axs[0].bar(x_pos + i*width, arr[i, :], width, align='center', label=labels[i], color=colors[i])
    axs[1].bar(x_pos + i*width, arr[i, :], width, align='center', label=labels[i], color=colors[i])
    axs[0].legend()
    axs[1].legend()
    
for subplot in ax:
        subplot.set_xlabel("the top five industry sectors")
        subplot.set_ylabel("Number of attack")
        subplot.set_title("Type of attack by top five industry sectors")
        subplot.set_xticks(x_pos[:4]+width/2)
        subplot.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=89.5)
#         subplot.legend()
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. But the major problem here is that I don't get the graph that is shown in (desired_output) image link given above. I get two similar bar graphs , however I want Stacked bar plot and group bar plot both. Thanks for the help. looking forward for more help.

Comment: I was aware that the issue was that the legend was not displayed, so I did not know that you wanted a stacked graph. Please refer to the [official reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-stacked-py) for an explanation.